# Error: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.Failed

Tags: ios, red5, rtmpd

Using librtmp(rtmpdump),I have these 2 methods in my applications, namely:

```
RTMP_Connect(RTMP *r,NULL)
```

and

```
RTMP_ConnectStream(RTMP *r,0)
```

to connect to red5 server and publish streams to the server.

When `RTMP_ConnectStream(RTMP *r,0)` gets executed, the following error appears in the log

> **Error: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.Failed**

and thus the connection to the server is aborted.

Can someone tell me why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into how ffmpeg or xuggler use librtmp to access publish or playback on Red5. I know their implementation works for both since I've used it at a high level many times. I'm not a C-guy so I can't help you anymore than that.

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt get you. Will I be able to see how xuggler is using librtmp? Can you provide some links which will be helpfull?